# Using Chromecast with packaged Chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome-app, chromecast, google-cast

I'm working to create a sender app in Chrome (34.0.1847.137, on 10.9), but rather than merely be a standard webpage, I'd like to package it into a Chrome App.

All of my code works fine tested as a standard webpage, but when packaged as an app, because there is no Chromecast button (normally next to address bar), it seems impossible to let the user even know that it's there even though through the console I can see that a receiver was identified.

Is there a way to reveal that button to the user or (even better) programmatically launch the receiver app on the Chromecast without needing the user to press any buttons?

Comment: While I don't have direct experience with this, I would suggest that you investigate the Chromecast API. Perhaps that's the way to provide the functionality your app needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Chromecast API isn't compatible with packaged apps quite yet. It's a known issue that's being worked on so hopefully it won't be a problem for much longer! In the mean time, you can track this Chrome bug to stay in the loop:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287254

Comment: Thanks!  It's good to know it wasn't just me.  It's not the end of the world for my project since using Chromecast requires the internet  anyways (crossing fingers for offline modes!) so I can just direct users to the webpages in the meantime.

Comment: @guifa I added an answer with one possible solution, however unless you need immediate Chromecast support I would wait for official support.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be to use the [chrome.sockets.tcpServer](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer) API to create your own web server and then serve a page which uses the [Chrome Cast Chrome Sender API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/)

You would still require users to install the official [Google Cast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd?hl=en) extension, it will act as a bridge between your packaged app and the Chromecast device.

If you would like to see this in action you can check out an app which uses this solution here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flair-player/mpkhmenokpjamhajlajnldibdjkacgcp

As you can see below, the address 127.0.0.1:8010/index.html is served using the chrome.sockets.tcpServer API, it then communicates with the Google Cast extension, and messages are sent between the app and the extension/device using AJAX.

[image: Page served by Chrome app using chrome.sockets.tcpServer]